# Get path to test resource file with Robolectric 3.0

Tags: resources, robolectric

I almost migrated all tests to Robolectric 3.0. It was huge deal :)

I have last failing test because I can not access test database that I used for migration tests. Next code produces NPE:

```
String filePath = getClass().getResource( "/test.db" ).toURI().getPath();
```

Do you know a way how to get absolute path to this file in Robolectric 3.0? I want to avoid hardcoding since I want to have test working on all machines

Comment: Hey Eugen.  Is the line above from your test or from the application code?  Are you trying to get the absolute path from the test machine or are you trying to get the absolute path of the file as it would be on a device?

Comment: Hey @abest, it is line from test code. I'm copying prepared database for test migration specific things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe will be helpful for someone. My code:

```
private void copyTestDatabase( String resourceDBName )
    throws URISyntaxException, IOException
{
    String filePath = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getPackageResourcePath() + "/src/test/res" + resourceDBName;

    String destinationPath = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getDatabasePath( "<my-db-name>.db" ).getAbsolutePath();

    File to = new File( destinationPath );
    to.mkdirs();
    to.delete();

    Files.copy( new File( filePath ), to );
}
```

Let me know if you have more elegant solution. Post the answer I will accept it